# Postgress between is not giving accurate data

Tags: php, postgresql, date

i have a database of hospital records, when user mention FROM and To date , then data between these two dates should be fetched.
`where datamonth '$fdate' BETWEEN datamonth '$tdate'`

but it fetches the data for extra months ,
for example if user want to fetch data from jan 2020 to feb 2020 , it fetches these two along with some other values

please guide me where i am doing a mistake.

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data and table structure and queries you have tried.

Comment: Your example can't return anything, as it has multiple syntax errors.

Comment: An answer to your question will not happen until you provide the information requested above and also  the output from; ```show datestyle;``` and ```show lc_time;``` in ```psql```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
WHERE datamonth >= DATE '$fdate' AND datamonth <= DATE '$tdate'
```

Your could also use `between`:

```
WHERE datamonth BETWEEN DATE '2020-01-01' AND DATE '2020-02-28'
```

Comment: i am already using between , but it fetch data of other months as well. 
when i use 1st method this error comes
Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "2009-01